# Bazaar commands revno and version-info disagree

Tags: version-control, bazaar

If you update your working tree to an earlier revision, then `bzr revno` reports the latest revision in the repository, not the revision of your working tree. `bzr version-info` however, reports the revision of your working tree. Why the difference?

```
> bzr up
 M  file1.txt
 M  file2.txt
All changes applied successfully.                                              
Updated to revision 1000 of branch bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~foo/bar/baz
> bzr up -r969
 M  file2.txt
All changes applied successfully.                                              
Updated to revision 969 of branch bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~foo/bar/baz
> bzr revno
1000
> bzr version-info
revision-id: foo@example.com-20101014072808-xo8f7r0oad9fjelaoi9
date: 2010-10-14 12:58:08 +0530
build-date: 2010-11-05 11:03:20 -0700
revno: 969
branch-nick: baz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the `bzr revno` command has two modes: repository and tree. You can execute `bzr revno --tree` to find the revision of the working tree.